# Problem when executing a script with two user interactions with Tkinker in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a script with two interactions with user. To do this, i use Tkinter. The first interaction is to get date while the second one is to get filename selection. The script runs fine for the first time execution. However, it seems that it hangs for the second run or more. I always need to restart Consoles in Spyder to make it runs again.

When i run in debug mode for the second run, it seems that the script stuck in root.mainloop() of the first user interaction. The script also runs fine for multiple executions if the second interaction to ask file selection is not there. Please find the code i wrote below. What could be the problem for this code?

```
def GetDate():
    def my_function():
        global date
        date = my_entry.get()
        root.destroy()
        return()

    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label = tk.Label(root, text = "Enter date (YYYYMMDD): ")
    my_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    my_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    my_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    my_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = my_function)
    my_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    root.mainloop()

GetDate()

tk.Tk().withdraw()
filenameDat = askopenfilename(initialdir = dayfold, filetypes=[("Dat", "*.xls*")], title = 'Open Input File')
```

'dayfold' is variable where the default initial directory will be prompted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the previous instance of `Tk()` created by the line `tk.Tk().withdraw()` still exists in the second run, so `root.mainloop()` inside `GetDate()` will not return as there is still other instance of `Tk()`.

You need to destroy the instance of `Tk()` as below:

```py
...

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
filenameDat = askopenfilename(initialdir = dayfold, filetypes=[("Dat", "*.xls*")], title = 'Open Input File')
root.destroy() # destroy the root window
```

Comment: You are right.. look into addition step i did by restarting the kernel is actually forcing the previouse instance of Tk() to be shut down. thanks for your answer.